# How to maintain the sequence of the rows on deleting and after adding the rows to it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, schema

In JavaScript, when we add row then the sequence after addition works
fine. However, lets assume I have added 3 rows and I have to delete
the 2nd row so after deleting the 2nd row the position of the 3rd row
should be displayed as position 2 but here it is still displayed as
position 3. Hence I would like to have a help regarding solving this
error for me. I want to re-sequence the result as shown in below
example.

```
   <script> {
          "itemListElement": [{
        "@type": "ListItem", 
        "position": 1, 
         "name": "aa",
         "item": "1"     },{
         "@type": "ListItem", 
         "position": 2, 
         "name": "bb",
         "item": "2"     },{
         "@type": "ListItem", 
         "position": 3, 
         "name": "cc",
         "item": "3"     }] }
 </script>
```

In addition, I am not using Angular/Vue. I am new to JavaScript so
please guide me in JS.

```js
 window.globalCounter = 2;

                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#add").on("click", function () {
                        var data = '<tr id="' + window.globalCounter + '"><td>' + window.globalCounter + '</td><td><input type="text" data-id="' + window.globalCounter + '" name="from_value' + window.globalCounter + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Page #" id="page' + window.globalCounter + '" oninput="myFunction(' + window.globalCounter + ')"></td><td><input name="to_value' + window.globalCounter + '" type="text" placeholder="URL" id="url' + window.globalCounter + '" class="form-control" oninput="myFunctionurl(' + window.globalCounter + ')"/></td><td><button class="delete-row btn btn-primary" type="button" id="delete">Delete</button></td></tr>';
                        $("tbody").append(data);
                        var objTo = document.getElementById('codes');

                        var divtest = document.createElement('span');
                        divtest.className = 'new_code'+window.globalCounter;
                        divtest.innerHTML = `,{
                                                "@type": "ListItem",
                                                "position": `+window.globalCounter+`,
                                                "name": <span class="demo`+window.globalCounter+`"></span>,
                                                "item": <span class="demourl`+window.globalCounter+`"></span>
                                            }`;

                        objTo.appendChild(divtest);
                        window.globalCounter++;
                    });

                    $("tbody").on("click", "#delete", function (ev) {
                        var $currentTableRow = $(ev.currentTarget).parents('tr')[0];
                        
                        var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
                        if(trid>1) {
                             $currentTableRow.remove(); 
                             $('.new_code'+trid).remove();  
                            
                             //$("#test-table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                             window.globalCounter--; 
                        }else {
                            alert("1st row not dlt");
                        }

                        
                        
  
                        $('table').find('tr').each(function (index) {
                           
                            var firstTDDomEl = $(this).find('td')[0];
                            var $firstTDJQObject = $(firstTDDomEl);
                            $firstTDJQObject.text(index + 1); 
                            //$("#test-table").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                            
                            
                        });
                    });


                });
                
                
   function myFunction(a) {
            var x = document.getElementById("page"+a).value; 
        // console.log('<span class="token string">'+x+'</span>');
            $(".demo"+a).html('"<span class="token string">'+x+'</span>"');
            }
            
            
            
  function myFunctionurl(b) {
            var x = document.getElementById("url"+b).value; 
        // console.log('<span class="token string">'+x+'</span>');
            $(".demourl"+b).html('"<span class="token string">'+x+'</span>"');
            }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row align-items-center justify-content-lg-between justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 mt-0 p-5 bg-white rounded-custom">
                        <table id="test-table" class="table table-condensed">
                             
                            <tbody id="test-body">
                                <tr id="1">
                                    <td>1</td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='from_value1' data-id="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Page #" id="page1" oninput="myFunction(1)">
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                    <input type="text" name='to_value1' class="form-control" placeholder="URL" id="url1" oninput="myFunctionurl(1)">
                                    </td>  
                                    <td><button class='delete-row btn btn-primary' type='button' id="delete">Delete</button></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table> 
                        <button id="add" class='btn btn-primary' type='button'>Add Row</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-7 mt-0 p-4 bg-white rounded-custom">
                    
                    <div class="code-box-copy">
                        <button class="code-box-copy__btn" data-clipboard-target="#example-initialization-with-parameters" title="Copy"></button>
                        <pre>
                            <div class="language-js" style="position: relative;left: -94px;" id="example-initialization-with-parameters">
                                &lt;script"&gt;
                                {
                                     
                                    "itemListElement": [{
                                        "@type": "ListItem", 
                                        "position": 1, 
                                        "name": <span class="demo1"></span>,
                                        "item": <span class="demourl1"></span>
                                    }<span id="codes"></span>
                                  ]
                                }
                                &lt;/script&gt;
                            </div>
                        </pre>
                                            
                    </div>
                         
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: The "position" property in the "itemListElement" array should not be needed. Arrays keep an index automatically, so you don't have to maintain one. To remove an item from an array you can use splice. For instance ```yourObject.itemListElement.splice(1, 1)```